# How did Magnus IV of Sweden come of age at 15?

Tags: middle-ages, 14th-century, norway, sweden

According to the Wikipedia article [Magnus IV of Sweden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_IV_of_Sweden)

> Magnus was declared to have come of age at 15 in 1331. This caused resistance in Norway, where a statute from 1302 made clear that kings came of age at the age of 20, and a rising by Erling Vidkunsson and other Norwegian nobles ensued. In 1333, the rebels submitted to king Magnus.

Who declared him to come of age and why? Was it his own idea? Why couldn't they wait for 5 more years? Which enemies were they afraid of?

Comment: You want to get the rightful king on the throne as soon as possible, usually. Otherwise power-hungry regents/nobles can make their move. That's the obvious answer I think, and probably the correct one.

Comment: OK, but I want more factual details. Who was behind the declaration? Which enemies they were afraid of? etc.

Comment: Ah, fair enough then. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There were two main issues. The first was that the SWEDISH age of majority was 16. Queen Christina, daughter of Gustav Adolfus, was offered the crown at age 16, but by her own request, her coronation was delayed until she was nearly 18 (so she could finish her education). This was, of course, in opposition to the Norwegian statutes, which had the king's age of majority at 20.

The more pressing issue was the power struggle between the king's mother, the Duchess Ingeborg (herself a Norwegian), and other Norwegians, who steadily moved to curb her power.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingeborg_of_Norway

The idea of crowning her son king at age 15 (a year ahead of the Swedish practice), was a countermove on her part.